# My desktop disappeared, how do I get it back?

Tags: 12.04, unity

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. This morning when I logged into my Ubuntu, after login screen the complete desktop was empty, the only operation I could perform is right-click and open terminal.

What I've tried:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> `unity --reset` : didn't work
2. From terminal `unity --reset` : didn't work
3. And from login screen selecting **Ubuntu 2D** and that also didn't solve the problem.

My laptop is Toshiba SA-60 onboard ATI graphic card with 1 GB RAM.

Please tell me how to solve this problem. I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu as whenever I install a I/O error pops up, forget about that. I don't want to reinstall Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: I accidentally removed python, after that ubuntu-desktop dissapeared, I didn't have an access to standart terminal. Thankful to this post I ran `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and installed ubuntu-desktop directly by command **`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`**

Comment: In my own case, `sudo plasma_session` solved the problem!

Answer (score 10):

- Install `gnome-tweak-tool`.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

- Go to **Desktop** list item. Make sure *Have file manager handle the desktop* is turned ON.

  [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes something strange can happen. Unity --reset says "this should never happen... report a bug". But help of community makes a difference.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Alas, this option no longer exists.

Comment: True, the option has been renamed as "Icons on Desktop". However it works as the old one.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I was unable to reset unity. I finally solved by reinstalling `libgrail5`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgrail5
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is kind of weird. Because you have tried the right things to reset unity.

Lets try once again,

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login and then enter these commands one by one.

`sudo lightdm stop`

`gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1`

`unity --reset-icons`

`unity --reset`

Have you played with any config file, x org configuration last time?

`sudo reboot now`

Comment: dude its not happening, its giving errors n i can't even post them

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgrail5
```

I have tried all the unity re-installs even going back to gnome.
this took me 3 hours , but above command did the trick.
My mistake was to tweak compiz, i know they give warnings ,but we run linux so what do 
you expect.

Precise desktop wallpaper no icons or anything I was ready to reinstall ,but still i did like to know I am not a geek or a newbie but something in between.

regards